# R: Choropleth map with ggplot2 (join attributes)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, shapefile

I was trying to create a choropleth map using ggplot2 and a public shape-file of Switzerland (it is included in [this zip-file](http://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.swisstopo-vd.ortschaftenverzeichnis_plz/PLZO_SHP_LV95.zip): PLZO_PLZ.shp)

```r
library(rgdal)    
library(ggplot2)   
library(ggmap)   
library(broom)

# Load Shapefile
shapefile <- readOGR(file.choose())

# Next the shapefile has to be converted to a dataframe for use in ggplot2
shapefile_df <- fortify(shapefile)

ggplot(data = shapefile_df) +
  geom_path(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),  color="black") +
  theme_void()
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

However, I don't want to plot the map only, I also want to color the different municipalities according to certain attributes. Each municipality has a four-digit zip code (called "PLZ"). These values can be seen in `shapefile$PLZ`.

But how can I assign attributes to certain municipalities? An example:

```r
fakeData <- data.frame(PLZ = c(8001, 8002, 8048), values = c(20, 40, 99))
```

I would like to colour the municipalities 8001, 8002 and 8048. But how can I join the variable `values` into `shapefile` or `shapefile_df`? So that I can plot it like this:

```r
ggplot(data = shapefile_df) +
  geom_path(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = values),  color="black") +
  theme_void()
```

If I try "left_join" on `shapefile` the error message is that the method is not applicable to an object of the class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial')". In `shapefile_df` however, there is no variable `PLZ` any more. I have also tried

```r
shapefile@data$id <- rownames(shapefile@data)
shapefile_df <- fortify(shapefile, region = "PLZ")
```

which leads to the following error: `Error in maptools::unionSpatialPolygons(cp, attr[, region]) :  isTRUE(gpclibPermitStatus()) is not TRUE`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the `sf` package to read the shapefile. Then you can do the `left_join` without any problems. Finally, you can do the plot using `geom_sf` and change the fill default values for NA from gray to transparent using `scale_fill_distiller` (you can also choose the fill palette for non-NA values).

```
library(sf)

# Read shapefile as sf
shapefile_df <- st_read(file.choose())

# Left_join by PLZ
shapefile_df <- shapefile_df %>%
  left_join(fakeData, by = "PLZ")

# Do plot
ggplot(shapefile_df, 
       aes(fill = values)) + 
  # Plot sf 
  geom_sf(show.legend = F) +
  # Indicate fill palette and set NA values to transparent
  scale_fill_distiller(type = "seq",
                       palette = "Blues",
                       na.value = "transparent") +
  # Add void theme
  theme_void()
```